# For $p\in\Bbb C[X]$ with $p_n=1$ show that $|p(z)|>R$ whenever $|z|>R$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification, complex-numbers

> For $p\in\Bbb C[X]$ with $p_n=1$ show that $|p(z)|>R$ whenever $|z|>R$. Where
>
> $$R:=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|$$

(This is the exercise $11$ of *Analysis I* of Amann and Escher, on page $109$.)

We have that $p$ is a polynomial of the kind

$$p=X^n+p_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots+p_1X+p_0$$

where the  coefficients $p_k\in\Bbb C$. And the polynomial function induced from $p$ is defined as

$$p(z)=z^n+p_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+p_1z+p_0$$ and $z\in\Bbb C$. I dont understand this problem or something is wrong in the textbook. Notice that if I choose, by example, the polynomial $p=X-0.1$ and $z=1.2$ then I get

$$|z|=1.2>1+|-0.1|=1.1\tag{1}$$

but then is false that

$$|1.2-0.1|>1+|-0.1|\tag{2}$$

Maybe the inequality must be $\ge$ instead of $>$? I checked the text and I copied correctly. Maybe Im misunderstanding something.

Any hint or clarification will be appreciated, thank you.

---

#### Proof

Check this proof please. Using the reversed triangle inequality we have that

$$|p(z)|=\Big|z^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_k z^k\Big|\ge \left||z|^n-\Big|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_kz^k\Big|\right|$$

Now, observe that if $|z|>R$ then $|z|>1$ what implies that $|z|^{n-1}>|z|^k$ for $0\le k<n-1$. Then

$$|z|^n>|z|^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|>\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k||z|^k\ge\Big|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_kz^k\Big|$$

Then for $|z|>R$ it is true that

$$|p(z)|\ge \left||z|^n-\Big|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_kz^k\Big|\right|\ge\left||z|^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k||z|^k\right|>\Bigg||z|^n-|z|^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Bigg|$$

Then

$$|p(z)|>\Big||z|^n-|z|^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big|=|z|^{n-1}\Big||z|-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big|>\\>\Big(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big)^{n-1}\Big|1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big|=\Big(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big)^{n-1}$$

And finally from the last inequality we have that

$$|p(z)|>\Big(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big)^{n-1}\ge 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|$$

whenever $n\ge 2$.$\Box$

Comment: What are $p_0, \dots , p_n$? How are they related to $p$?

Comment: @Crostul $p_k$ are the coefficients of $p$. And $p=\sum p_k X^k$ is a polynomial.

Comment: I found this PDF http://marta05.w.staszic.waw.pl/~marta05/inne/Amann1.pdf page 109. So it's the 1st version, i.e. given $|z| > R$ prove $|p(z)| > R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the last step of your inequality:

$$\Big(1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|\Big)^{n-1} \geq 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_k|$$
is only true if $n \geq 2$, and you get strict inequality for $n \geq 3$.

For $n=2$ you get equality, which is enough to prove the desired relation.

As you observed, for $n=1$ the inequality is equivalent to proving that 
for $|z|>1+|a|$ we have
$$|z+a|>1+|a|$$
which is not always true. Indeed, if $z=-Ca$ with $C\in (0, \infty)$ the  inequality becomes 
$$(C-1)|a| >1 \Rightarrow (C-2)|a|>2$$

Comment: Ah, you solved the mystery. Thank you very much. It seems that the problem need the condition $n\ge 2$.