# Absolute value of complex polynomial is larger than sum of absolute values of coefficients

Tags: inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers

This is Exercise 11 from page 109 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

**Exercise:**

> For $p = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} +\dots+ a_1X + a_0 \in\mathbb C[X],$ define $R := 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k|$. Show that $|p(z)| > R$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|z| > R$.

**My attempt:**

I thought it wouldn't be too hard to show that

\begin{align}
\lvert z^n \rvert + \lvert a_{n - 1} \rvert \lvert z^{n - 1} \rvert + \dots + \lvert a_1 \rvert \lvert z \rvert + \lvert a_0 \rvert &> R
\end{align}

but then I realized that this is an approach from the wrong angle because $\lvert p(z) \rvert$ is smaller than the separated expression on the left, not larger. In other words, the triangle inequality works the wrong way for my approach to work.

**Questions and comments:**

There is supposedly a proof to the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950661/for-p-in-bbb-cx-with-p-n-1-show-that-pzr-whenever-zr). The proof looks kind of messy and hard to follow, at least for me. Does anyone think the linked solution is the right way to solve this exercise?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes,  the proof in that link is the right way to prove this inequality.